# Visual Studio 2015 error - saved settings file CurrentSettings.vssettings cannot be found

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ide

After running Windows updates and restarting my workstation, I get the error shown below when opening Visual Studio 2015. I clicked the OK button and VS opened. However, my solutions wouldn't load.

The error message said to change the `CurrentSettings.vssettings` file on the 'Import and Export Settings' Tools Options page. However, I was unable to figure out how to do this, and the suggestions I found online (including suggested registry updates) didn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I selected "Import and Export Settings... from the Visual Studio Tools menu. Then, on the Import and Export Settings Wizard screen that came up, I selected the "Reset all settings" option and clicked the Next button. Once these steps were completed, I was able to load my solutions again.

[image]